# A Dictionary Of Methods With Different Definitions

Tags: .net, dictionary, delegates

I have a swath of third-party API classes (23 and counting) that I need to create some test calls for using existing calls as proxies (as there are no defined dedicated test calls), eg `GetTitles()`, `GetCountries()`, etc.

To date, I've replicated about 20 lines of code under each of the APIs' namespaces, which obviously creates a lot of maintenance issues. But I would like to condense this down to a single method sitting in a class inherited by each (partial) API class.

This means that each API/class would have added to it by the inherited `Helper` class a `TestConnection()` method. The `TestConnection()` method then needs to know which proxy test call to call. (I've determined the calling class and therefore can work out which call to make using `this.GetType()` etc, yielding "Api1", "Api2", etc.)

I've also read about using delegates to dynamically make the proxy test call.

BUT ...

I wanted to put these delegates into a `TestCalls` Dictionary (of string caller, TestCall delegate) where `TestCall` is a defined Delegate and call them like this:

`TestCalls[caller].Invoke()`

However, the issue is two-fold:

1. Not all of the proxy calls have the same signature in terms of arguments and return type*, and
2. At least one proxy call (so far) requires a single string argument (the others, although they have either no or optional arguments, I don't make the calls using them).

(* Because I'm not interested in the return value, just whether or not the call succeeds, I can use `object` as the return type for all of the calls.)

Initially, I had this:

```
private delegate object TestCall();
private static Dictionary<string, TestCall> TestCalls = new Dictionary<string, TestCall>();

TestCalls.Add("Api1", Api1.GetTitles);
TestCalls.Add("Api2", Api2.GetCountries);
TestCalls.Add("Api3", Api3.GetCurrencies);
TestCalls.Add("Api4", Api4.GetNameFormats);
```

But this doesn't compile because the method signatures are not the same (and I have no control over these).

So after playing around and reading further, I've ended up creating several different delegate definitions and add the proxy calls individually, eg:

```
private delegate object TestCall1();
private delegate object TestCall2(bool? a1);
private delegate object TestCall3(int? a1, string a2, bool? a3);
private static Dictionary<string, Delegate> TestCalls = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

TestCalls.Add("Api1", new TestCall1(Api1.GetTitles));
TestCalls.Add("Api2", new TestCall1(Api2.GetCountries));
TestCalls.Add("Api3", new TestCall2(Api3.GetCurrencies));
TestCalls.Add("Api4", new TestCall3(Api4.GetNameFormats));
```

This works (apart from needing to add the argument value to one call which I would really like to avoid).

But it's way more convoluted than I was hoping for.

I've looked at using the defined `Func` delegate, raw strings representing the methods, etc and nothing seems to be as elegant/maintainable/intuitive as I'd like.

Does anyone have any suggestions for "genericizing" the proxy call delegates? Or a completely different approach?

Ideally, I'd be able to have a dictionary of explicit proxy calls, including any arguments such as `Api5.GetSomething("StringArg")` or `Api6.GetAnother(IntArg)` so that I don't have to conditionally add this in the call block.

As an aside, to me it makes no sense to enforce argument provision/number if the arguments are optional; when I manually call a method with optional arguments and don't provide them, everything's fine. Why impose a constriction using a delegate??

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
class ApiHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> TestCalls= new Dictionary<string, string>();

    static ApiHelper()
    {
        TestCalls.Add("Api1", "GetTitles");
        TestCalls.Add("Api2", "GetCountries");
        TestCalls.Add("Api3", "GetCurrencies");
        TestCalls.Add("Api4", "GetNameFormats");
        ...

    bool TestConnection()
    {
        string caller = GetType().FullName.Split(new char[] {'.'})[1]; // Api1, Api2, ...
        try
        {
            MethodInfo oMethod = GetType().GetMethod(TestCalls[caller]);
            object[] params = new object[method.GetParameters().Length];
            if (caller == "Api2") params[0] = "AnArg"; // Add an argument to this call
            var result = oMethod.Invoke(this, params);
            TestConnectionMsg = $"The API connection test passed.";
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            TestConnectionMsg = $"The API connection test failed: {x.Message}.";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This code derives the test call's required - tho optional! - parameter list which the invocation expects and makes the call, falling through to success or failing through to the catch block.

This isn't the most elegant solution I was looking for but it works fine and is robust enough.